# Crawling Ethereum transactions from one address

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I want to crawl the ETH blockchain and to get transactions that are made to or from a given wallet address.
I wrote a code with a help of `web3.py` but I'm getting some strange results.
I'm finding the transactions but the value of the transaction is 0.
How is that possible?
I have head that there are differences between wallet addresses and smart contract addresses, but I can not find how to make a difference between them. Also, how to crawl amount of ERC20 tokens that are in the transaction?

```
from web3 import Web3
from datetime import datetime

# Defining url for collecting ETH transactions
infura_url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Making connections with infra url
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
print("Connection is successful:", web3.isConnected())


# Wallet Address
account = "0xaa7a9ca87d3694b5755f213b5d04094b8d0f0a6f"
# Checking the balance for that address (in WEIs)
try:
    print("Input Address:", account)
    balance = web3.eth.getBalance(account)
except:
    # If its not a lowercase()
    account = Web3.toChecksumAddress(account)
    print("Input Address:", account)
    balance = web3.eth.getBalance(account)

# Print balance in WEIs
print("Balance in WEIs:", balance)

# Converting account balance to ETH
balanceWEI = web3.fromWei(balance, "ether")
print("Balance in ETH:", balanceWEI)


# Defining start block and latest block
start_block = web3.eth.blockNumber-3000
end_block = web3.eth.blockNumber


for block_num in range(start_block, end_block):

    current_block = block_num
    remaining_num_of_blocks = end_block - block_num
    progress = round(100*(block_num - start_block) / (end_block - start_block), 2)
    #print('Fetching block {}, remaining:{}, progress: {}%'.format(current_block, remaining_num_of_blocks, progress))

    # Get block with specific number with all transactions
    block = web3.eth.getBlock(block_num, full_transactions=True)
    block_time = block.timestamp
    block_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(block_time)
    print("Time of the processed block:", block_time)

    list_of_block_transactions = block.transactions

    for transaction in list_of_block_transactions:

        to_account = transaction['to']
        from_account = transaction['from']

        if to_account == account:
            print("To account:", to_account)         
            to_match = True
        else:
            to_match = False            


        if from_account == account:
            print("From account:", from_account)
            from_account = True
            
        else:
            from_account = False            

    
        if to_match == True or from_account == True:
            print("Found Transaction with HASH:", transaction['hash'])
            print("Found Transaction with HASH-HEX:", transaction['hash'].hex())
            print("Found Transaction with value:", transaction['value']) # this value is always 0
            print("Found Transaction with gas:", transaction['gas']) # this value is more than 0
            
            print()
```

How is this possible, I have crawled the last 3000 blocks, but I have also tried with the last 25000 blocks and the result is the same.
This is an example of the transaction that I'm getting.

```
    AttributeDict({'blockHash': HexBytes('0xb8a0c912053a6e89658158a30912fc9974e280b1009967ed0c5658b89324aaeb'), 'blockNumber': 13385037, 
    'from': '0xC0e32e544A82D9396B0b52d90B484f831f89Fd83', 
    'gas': 106070, 
    'gasPrice': 70000000000, 
    'hash': HexBytes('0x62f0eefbedc7445de511a1d09682f7674152335bce0eec52c8c3f517990e5602'), 
'input': '0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000a1d8d972560c2f8144af871db508f0b0b10a3fbf0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003ecdc77a726c9df8000', 
    'nonce': 446, 
    'r': HexBytes('0x482fde01e1a71ae4328a2ddab169e56fe9be095c9ebd26c2ddd022caedb2924d'), 
    's': HexBytes('0x7bce8c69d5832dbe59c9742ba53f714be8693383dee895c333855a3f85391c70'), 
   'to': '0xaA7a9CA87d3694B5755f213B5D04094b8d0F0A6F', 
    'transactionIndex': 296, 
    'type': '0x0', 
    'v': 37, 
    'value': 0})
```

Answer (score 0):

Transactions sent to smart contracts do not need value. As you can see from `input` it is a smart contract transaction.

Comment: Can you tell me more about that?
How can I see that from input, how to get eth values in smart contracts?

Comment: Unfortunately how Ethereum transactions work generally are out of the scope of this question. Here is some random tutorial to study more https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/ - I suggest studying and understanding the meaning of different items in the context and generally looking for Ethereum learning materials

Comment: I understand how ETH transactions work, but how can I see from the input that its smart contract transaction? How can I see the amount thats transacted?